# Attirbute based routing for ASP.Net controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know attribute based routing works on action level but can I use same at controller level for following scenario?

I have a controller with name `C1Controller` but I want when url contains `C1` or `C2` or `C3` then `C1Controller` to invoke. How to use `Route` attribute to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give an example url that contains the `C1` or `C2` that would map to `C1Controller`. This is so that a proper route template can be suggested to satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from a post

"The most correct way would be to create a class that inherits ActionFilterAttribute and override OnActionExecuting method. This can then be registered in the GlobalFilters in Global.asax.cs"

Like:

```
public class InspectActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       //Check URL for c1, c2 ... and redirect if found
   }
}
```

To use it, just add it to the global filters in global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new LogActionFilter());
}
```

Ref: [Intercept all calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383808/how-can-i-intercept-all-controller-calls-in-an-mvc-application)

[ASP.NET MVC 4 intercept all incoming requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726848/asp-net-mvc-4-intercept-all-incoming-requests)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
public class TheActionFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        if (controllerName !="C1" || controllerName !="C1" || controllerName !="C3")
             return;
        var redirectTarget = new RouteValueDictionary
           {{"action", "ActionName"}, {"controller", "ControllerName"}};
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTarget);      
        filterContext = new RedirectResult(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath)              // The session you can get from the context like that:
        var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
    }
}
```

In Your Controller

```
[TheActionFilter]
public class BookController : Controller
{
    // Your Action Results
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking about *routing*. This action filter does a *redirect*. It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: It will be redirect to another page

Comment: Yes, it will send a 302 HTTP response to the browser telling it to lookup a new location on the server. Routing avoids the round trip across the network by directly accessing the action method on the server-side.

Comment: For that We need to use [Route("ActionName")] this attribute